# Chemical reaction to create a delayed mark on skin

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I'm looking for a dye or chemical reaction that can create a mark on the hand.

Substance A is placed on hand in advance.  When substance B is added, the reaction creates a black mark or stain on the hand.

Ideally, after a delay of a few seconds, a stain or mark appears on the hand. It could possibly be two clear substances that when mixed together create the reaction.

Does anyone have experience with anything that might achieve this effect?  I'm working on this for a visual experiment.

Comment: I have a feeling that people would object in strongest terms against you leaving marks on them.